# What does "Soft close" mean and how does it work?

Tags: install4j

I created a little test application to place a tray icon in the system tray bar of windows. The installation with install4j is working well and also the uninstall process by using the "Terminate immediately" option for the "Check for running system" action is working. But when the application is killed the tray icon still exists in the system tray bar until someone is hovering the icon. Then the icon diapear. So I thought about to implement a runtime hookup to the application main class to remove the icon from the system tray before the vm is terminated. I switched the mode of the install4j action to "Soft close immediately". But that causes an error saying application is still running. Now I am wondering how this option is working and what the "Soft close" means. Do this innitiate the vm shutdown? In the "Check for ..." action I disabled the "Inluding launcher" option and added the generated executable directly for the additional executables.

PS: we are using version 6.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

"Soft close" sends a `WM_CLOSE` message to all visible windows of the process. "Terminate" kills the process. If there is only a tray icon, there will be no visible window and soft close will not work.